# Why does my keyboard not work?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad

Ok, so recently I've decided to try linux on a laptop, after performing the updates that the system required, my laptop keyboard and touchpad stopped working. However, external mouse and keyboard work perfectly.
Also, in the grub menu, there is a version of Linux where the keyboard and mouse work. I've already tried things like installing "xserver-xorg-input-all" and it doesn't make anything.

Comment: If it works in one kernel version but not in an other/newer on it might be an error in that kernel. Have you tried to run update ? `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it

Comment: What OS & release are you talking about.  If you were using a LTS release and had issues with the upgrade of a kernel, you can always opt with using the GA kernel stack, which means you remain on the same kernel for the life of the product (only patches are applied).  You didn't provide any specifics though, what OS & release are you using, what you installed .. thus what you started with and what upgrades occurred...  (Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack options; GA or general, or HWE or hardware-enablement which causes the kernel to upgrade during the cycle... Chosen by install ISO)

Comment: user@Easynote-ENTF71BM:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
user@Easynote-ENTF71BM:~$ uname -a
Linux Easynote-ENTF71BM 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: `sudo dmesg | grep intel-vbtn` any output?

Comment: user@Easynote-ENTF71BM:~$ sudo dmesg | grep intel-vbtn

[   13.861270] acpi INT33D6:00: intel-vbtn: created platform device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ntel-vbtn.conf
```

with following content.

```
# Blacklist module intel-vbtn 
blacklist intel-vbtn
```

Please update the initrid from the concerned kernel.
[bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894017)