# Ubuntu20.10 not detecting laptop keyboard on installing

Tags: system-installation

Ubuntu 20.10 not detecting my laptop keyboard after langauge selection, even if langauge is left on English (USA) I cannot type either letter or numbers.

Comment: For a long shot.Easiest way is to use an external keyboard for installation and first boot for installed system. There  you can blacklist intel-vbtn https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293849/why-does-my-keyboard-not-work/1293879#1293879

Comment: I have just tried to install Lubuntu 20.10 as an easier option, the set up is easier and quicker unitl I get to langauge- keyboard even thoese this system detects the keyboard for the time zone setting, it still does not pick up the keyboard  n my Acer Estonia laptop, I spoke to  Canonical Ltd.UK and all I got was we cannot help you as you have nt got a support package, great start!!!!!!!!!!!!!