# Keyboard not working on ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, touchpad

On ubuntu 18, I have left my system for some time, some thing happened and now when I land on password screen I cant use my touchpad or keyboard.
Although keyboard is working fine on startup and on Bios setup but not on password screen.
I have updated dpkg packages by going to recovery mode via advanced ubuntu options.
Also tried to go to root shell via advanced ubuntu options and recovery mode.

I ran below command on root shell but it gives error saying "temporary failure resolving" and Failed to fetch pk.archive.ubuntu.com

> apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all

Cant ping google.com in that root shell as well.

Can anyone help

Comment: Not an answer/solution, just a suggestion: Try the current (and LTS) release, 22.04, in a live session. If it works correctly install it. 18.04 has less than a year of support left. there's no point in troubleshooting it if the current release just works.

Comment: Isn't `xserver-xorg-input-all` package preinstalled? Have you removed it, or what happened exactly?

Comment: Boot up normal and on the loggin screen press CTR+ALT+F1 and  login there.`dmesg | grep intel-vbtn` any output? If so try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293849/why-does-my-keyboard-not-work/1293879#1293879